# How to create MessageReceiver on subscription using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus

Tags: c#, azureservicebus, .net-standard

I'm trying to replace the .NET Framework NuGet package WindowsAzure.ServiceBus with .NET Standard Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus and I faced the problem. How to create an instance of MessageReceiver for Service Bus topic subscription? I can create it for a queue with the code:

```
var receiver = new MessageReceiver(connectionString, queueName);
var bytes = receiver.ReceiveAsync().Result.Body;
string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

but the MessageReceiver does not have a constructor for getting data from a Service Bus topic subscription.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer in the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus source code. It turned out that there are static functions in EntityNameHelper class that generate messaging entity paths. For example, for a subscription, it looks like

```
EntityNameHelper.FormatSubscriptionPath(topicName, subscriptionName)
```

So, full MessageReceiver initialization code looks like:

```
string path = EntityNameHelper.FormatSubscriptionPath(topicName, subscriptionName);
var receiver = new MessageReceiver(connectionString, path);
var bytes = receiver.ReceiveAsync().Result.Body;
string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Yuriy's excellent answer, `ServieBusConnectionStringBuilder` can also be used to contain the configuration data, which I find to be a little more concise.

```
var builder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString)
    {
        TransportType = TransportType.AmqpWebSockets,
        EntityPath = EntityNameHelper.FormatSubscriptionPath(topic, subscription)
    };

var messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver(builder);
```